# Custom tensorflow contradictory AVX2 / FMA messages?

Tags: tensorflow, julia

In Julia 0.6 official release, if I Pkg.add tensorflow and run the Pkg.test, shortly after the test starts I get a message about how my CPU supports various protocols such as AVX/2 FMA SSE and so on. Then later in the test process I get another message restating that AVX2 and FMA are not available. The AVX? issue is broadly addressed in other stackoverflow questions.

On recompile a custom version of tensorflow to include AVX / FMA and copy of the resulting tensorflow.so files to the Julia tensorflow deps/usr/bin, running the same Pkg.test() results in no
 first message, which seems to confirm that AVX2 and FMA are now in the binary, but the second message repeats, informing me again that AVX2 and FMA are not compiled in.

```
Test Summary:   | Pass  Total
shape_inference |  255    255
2018-06-08 09:55:41.794208: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
TensorBoard 1.8.0 at http://linux-k18k.suse:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Test Summary: |
show          | No tests
```

This may or may not be a contradiction in messages from tensorflow. Given a tensorflow.so library file, is there a way to confirm independently whether the AVX / FMA components were successfully compiled in?

Edit1: Ok so I found objdump and verified that some opt codes for AVX2 are in fact included in the .so library. This issue seems to involve tensorboard rather than tensorflow, but I don't qualify to add a tag for tensorboard (can someone help?). I'm wondering if the standalone tensorboard is pointed at the right libtensorflow? If it is getting information from another version this might explain why it thinks that the codes for AVX2 are missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved. For me the confusing thing was that it was tensorboard generating the message, not (as I thought) tensorflow itself. Tensorflow was quiet because it saw a valid binary capable of AVX2 and FMA, but tensorboard was doing a separate check which failed, at least in version 1.8. Tensorboard in fact does not do anything requiring AVX2 or FMA so the issue can be safely ignored. Version 1.9 of tensorflow/tensorboard now assesses AVX2 and FMA capability correctly and does not generate the warning message.